# Fragment disappears from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

Why does `FragmentTwo` disappear from the backstack in the following situation:

- My app has a `Fragment` called `FragmentOne` in an `Activity`.
- `FragmentOne` holds a `Button`. When clicked, it launches `FragmentTwo`, which is added to the `Fragment` backstack.
- `FragmentTwo` has a `Button`, which when clicked adds two tabs to the `ActionBar` linked to two `Fragments`, `FragmentThree` and `FragmentFour`. `FragmentThree` is visible.
- If I now click the back button, I expected to see `FragmentTwo`. Instead, I see `FragmentOne`.  Where did `FragmentTwo` go?

Before I override `onKeyDown()` and start implementing my own backstack for `Fragments` I wanted to ask if there is something obvious I am missing? Note there is no configuration change happening when testing this.

[image: enter link description here]

Details:

FragmentOne's button click handler contains:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();
```

FragmentTwo button click is handled in the Activity:

```
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    FragmentFour fragmentThree = new FragmentThree();
    FragmentFive fragmentFive = new FragmentFive();

    ActionBar.Tab tab = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Frag 3").setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<FragmentThree>(fragmentThree));
    getActionBar().addTab(tab);
    tab = getActionBar().newTab().setText("Frag 4").setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<FragmentFour>(fragmentFour));
    getActionBar().addTab(tab);
```

where the tab listener is:

```
public static class CustomTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements TabListener {
    Fragment fragment;

    public CustomTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

I if add more `Fragments` to backstack before `FragmentThree` is shown, it is always and only the `Fragment` immediately before `FragmentThree` that has disappeared.

When I leave the Tabbed user view by pressing the back key and return to `FragmentOne`, the tabs are still showing. I understand I need to reset the `ActionBar` to `NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD`, but it's not clear why `FragmentOne` is showing instead of `FragmentTwo`.

Comment: @Pierre Rymiortz, i also faced the same issue like you. please refer my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is if you build your tabs

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
}
```

gets called and the fragment before is not added to the backstack

did you try to call

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

in the Fragment Two button handling code.

But you need to implement `onBackPressed()` anyway to get rid of the tabs. I think I would make new activity with tabs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. An IllegalStateException is thrown if I add the addToBackStack method in OnTabSelected().

Comment: uh.. thats bad. maybe you can add the fragment to the backstack on the FragmentTwo button click.

Comment: After trying out different solutions I believe ActionBar Tabs were intended only as a top level navigation pattern, meaning the Tabs must be the starting point in the Fragment navigation (If someone can prove this wrong please do) for the Fragment backstack to work as expected. So in my example FragmentTwo must start an Activity which contains an ActionBar with two Tabs. This is what I ended up implementing. Since you mention this in your answer gabe I'll mark this as correct.

Answer (score 2):

@Pierre Rymiortz, i just did the workaround for the Issue. please refer the Code below.

```
public class StartActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    TabListener, OnBackStackChangedListener {

private Context mContext = null;

private ActionBar mActionBar;

private Tab mTab;

private Fragment mSelectFragment;

private final static int ONE = 0;
private final static int TWO = 1;
private final static int THREE = 2;
private final static int PLAYERS = 3;

private MenuItem mPlayerItem = null;

private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = null;

/**
 * by default is false - TABS were taken in the starting true - when we are
 * changing back to TABS from STANDARD
 */
private boolean mTabsChanges = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mContext = this;

    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // hiding the ActionBar icon
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // for displaying the Arrow button
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // hide Actionbar title
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create first Tab
    mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this);
    mTab.setText("One");
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);

    // Create Second Tab

    mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this);
    mTab.setText("Two");
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);

    // Create Three Tab
    mTab = mActionBar.newTab().setTabListener(this);
    mTab.setText("Three");
    mActionBar.addTab(mTab);

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mFragmentTransaction = ft;
    if (mTabsChanges) {
        // nothing to do here
        mTabsChanges = false;
    } else {
        switch (mActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex()) {
        case ONE:
            clearBackStack(mTabsChanges);
            mSelectFragment = new Fragment1();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectFragment, ONE + "");
            break;
        case TWO:
            clearBackStack(mTabsChanges);
            mSelectFragment = new Fragment2();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectFragment, TWO + "");
            break;
        case THREE:
            clearBackStack(mTabsChanges);
            mSelectFragment = new Fragment3();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectFragment, THREE + "");
            break;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(
            mContext,
            "tab unselected." + mActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex()
                    + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Toast.makeText(
            mContext,
            "tab reselected." + mActionBar.getSelectedNavigationIndex()
                    + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater mInflate = getSupportMenuInflater();
    mInflate.inflate(R.menu.header_menu, menu);

    mPlayerItem = menu.findItem(R.id.men_set_players);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.men_set_players) {
        addFragmentToStack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void addFragmentToStack() {

    // Add the fragment to the activity, pushing this transaction
    // on to the back stack.
    mActionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.menu_players));
    mSelectFragment = new PlayersFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectFragment, "Players");
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack("players");
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        int TOP = fm.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
        Log.i("BACKSTACK", TOP + ".."
                + fm.getBackStackEntryAt(TOP).getName());
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryAt(TOP).getName()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("players")) {
            if (mActionBar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) {
                mTabsChanges = false;
                mActionBar
                        .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            }
        } else {
            if (mActionBar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD) {
                mTabsChanges = true;
                mActionBar
                        .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            }
        }

    } else {
        if (mActionBar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD) {
            mTabsChanges = true;
            mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        } else if (mActionBar.getNavigationMode() == ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) {
            mTabsChanges = false;
        }
    }

    Toast.makeText(mContext,
            "FM Back count." + fm.getBackStackEntryCount(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void clearBackStack(boolean callFromSelection) {
    if (!callFromSelection) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            fm.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "callfromreapprearence",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use this code-block to replace fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, YOUR_FRAGMENT);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using this for the Fragment that disappears. See first code block in my question. For tabbed Fragments, addToBackStack doesn't work for me, see my comment to the gabe's reply.

Comment: call addToBackStack just before commit. all fragment actions fist then addToBackStack (if needed), then commit.

All fragment operations you should always begin with beginTransaction, then add/replace/remove fragments, then addToBackStack (optional) and commit at the end.

Comment: I tested it and it doesn't make a difference to call replace() before the addToBackStack() call. The way I understand it is that FragmentTransaction follows the Builder pattern and the order before commit() doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the `ft.remove` in the `onTabUnselected()` function since replace already does this.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion and deleted the line "ft.remove(fragment)", but unfortunately it doesn't change the behaviour, stills jumps from FragmentThree to FragmentOne when pressing back key.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you've shown above, you never add Fragment2 to the back stack.

@gabe, @Pierre, The reason you are getting an IllegalStateException by using `addToBackStack()` in the listener is documented in the API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html

```
public abstract void onTabSelected (ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
```

> Added in API level 11
>
> Called when a tab enters the selected state.
>
> Parameters tab     The tab that was selected
>
> ft     A FragmentTransaction for queuing fragment operations to execute during a tab switch. The previous tab's unselect and this tab's select will be executed in a single transaction.
>
> *This FragmentTransaction does not support being added to the back stack.*

The easy way around this is to get your own FragmentTransaction inside the TabListener by using the FragmentManager and add it to the back stack. Something like this

```
    public static class CustomTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements TabListener {
    Fragment fragment;

    public CustomTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction newFragTrans = fm.beginTransaction();
        newFragTrans.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
        newFragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        newFragTrans.commit()
        
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

I only modified onTabSelected, but you get the point. Also, don't forget to `commit()` this transaction because the listener will only automatically `commit()` the supplied `FragmentTransaction ft`

One last thing, ensure you are calling `addToBackStack()` after performing your transaction, because that's what you are adding to the stack, rather than the actual fragment.  In your code above this was not done for Fragment1's button click.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt for advice on how to build the TabListener. Unfortunately even with the new Tablistener code the problem persists. I do add FragmentTwo to backstack, see first code block in my Q.

Comment: Actually your code does not add FragmentTwo to backstack, based on what I see above. Remember, you are adding a transaction to the backstack. So, in this case you are removing fragmentOne and adding fragmentTwo (replace), then remembering this transition/transaction by adding it to the back stack, kind of like an undo action. Assuming, of course, the `ft.addToBackStack()` call is after the `ft.replace()`. If the code in the listener is not working, what are the errors/problems?